# What is the unit of "mem" and "memory" in /proc/net/sockstat

Tags: kernel, linux

What is the unit of mem and memory in /proc/net/sockstat? Bytes, KBytes, Pages?

```
[kbrandt@ny-kbrandt01: ~] cat /proc/net/sockstat
sockets: used 153
TCP: inuse 7 orphan 0 tw 0 alloc 8 mem 1
UDP: inuse 4 mem 3
UDPLITE: inuse 0
RAW: inuse 0
FRAG: inuse 0 memory 0
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There seems to be no documentation of this besides the kernel source itself, and I presume you don't want to dig quite that deep.

After digging through several pages of search results I finally found [one forum post](http://www.unix.com/302388593-post4.html) from someone who apparently did read the kernel source, which claims that the `mem` values for TCP and UDP are in kernel pages, while the `memory` value in FRAG is in bytes.

I glanced at the [corresponding sources](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/ident?i=tcp_memory_allocated) myself, and this *seems* to be true. Though, I am no kernel expert and frequently get lost in that maze...